# Android SQLite Column Sum

Tags: android, sqlite

I am stuck in getting the total sum of my SQLite column. The app keeps crashing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks =). Here's my code in my DatabaseHelper and Main Activity:

```
public class DatabaseOperator {
    private DataManager dataManager;
...
    public int getTotalExpenses()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = dataManager.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + Integer.valueOf(Expenses.C_TOTAL_PRICE) + ") FROM " + Expenses.TABLE, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int i = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    return i;
}

//MainActivity.class
TextView textTotalExpenses;
int totalExpenses;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

DatabaseOperator databaseOperator = new DatabaseOperator(this);
textTotalExpenses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTotalExpenses);
totalExpenses = databaseOperator.getTotalExpenses();
textTotalExpenses.setText(totalExpenses);
```

03-26 09:31:23.483 5818-5818/com.example.everydaybudgeting20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.everydaybudgeting20, PID: 5818
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.everydaybudgeting20/com.example.everydaybudgeting20.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "totalPrice"
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "totalPrice"
                                                                                   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:611)
                                                                                   at com.example.everydaybudgeting20.DatabaseOperator.getTotalExpenses(DatabaseOperator.java:229)
                                                                                   at com.example.everydaybudgeting20.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: Just posted it.

Comment: What are your colume name?

Comment: It's C_TOTAL_PRICE

Comment: Change String to int for your data type column C_Total_price

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed it myself. Thanks for all your help!

```
    public int getTotalExpenses()
{
    int total = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase database = dataManager.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM("+ Expenses.C_TOTAL_PRICE + ") FROM " + Expenses.TABLE, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        total = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext());
    return total;
}
```